# CloudWatchEvent から Lambda を起動する方法

Tags: aws, aws-lambda

Rails の管理画面で時間を指定して CloudWatchEvents から Lambda を起動するようなタスクを作りたいです
（タスクの中身は固定で時間だけユーザが指定できるようにする）

とりあえず画面部分は後回しで
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/sdk-for-ruby/v3/developer-guide/cw-example-send-events.html
を参考に ruby スクリプトから時間をパラメータに Lambda がよべるかテストコードを作成

CloudWatchEvent に put_rule, put_target するコードをかいて実行したところ 
CloudWatchEvent のAWSコンソールのイベントでトリガーに Lambda が表示されていて
ルールのメトリクス内でスケジュール Cron 式どおり起動されているのですが
Lambda は何の反応もありません

CloudWatchEvent が Lambda を呼び出すとき
（失敗した場合）のログってどこかに出ないんでしょうか

---

あと手順 2 の add-permission は rule を追加するたびに毎回やる必要があるのでしょうか

Lambda 側は固定で起動時間は何回も設定するのでそのたびにルールが別に作られることになりますが
put_rule の際に role を設定する項目があるので
ここと Lambda 側に固定のロールをセットするだけとはいかないのでしょうか

Comment: エラーログはAWSのコンソールから「CloudWatch→ログ」で出ていませんでしたでしょうか？すみません、私の環境では通常の起動ログしか出てないのでエラーログは確認できてないのですが、エラーも出力されないのかなと思いまして。

Comment: それらしいログは /aws/lambda/*, /aws/rds/* しかなくて対象の lambda のものはみあたらないです  lambda に来る前の /aws/cloud-watch-events 的なログがはかれるものなのでしょうか

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lambda.add_permission
を毎回やると起動するようにはなりました

あと put_target は１度だけでよくて
複数回やるとイベント来るたびに同じ Lambda が複数回呼び出さえてしまうようです